# How can I make two animated objects line up?

Tags: animation, export, unity

I have a animation of a enemy holding a bat. The bat is a separate object to the character, and the character's arms are IK'd to the bat. So it's two animations, one for each object.

I'm importing this into Unity, and for some reason these two objects don't seem to line up. It's mainly a problem with the bat, but the bat ends up by the character's feet. I have parented the bat to the enemy model root, but it still does not show correctly.

[image]

[image]

Would anyone more versed in animation know what could be happening? I'm not sure what's going on. It still follows the animation, but its way closer to world zero than it's supposed to be.

Comment: From the hierarchy, the Bat doesn't seem to be parented.  Did you use a Parented *modifier*?   Perhaps try to Apply the modifier before you export.

Comment: @james_t the bat is parented to the actual enemy fbx, the one with the Animator component. In Blender, it's not parented to anything.

Weirdly, I'm also noticing that for some animations it also doesn't animate.

Here's a picture of the blender hierarchy and modifiers:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/812122564926111814/1030510438741442571/unknown.png

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/812122564926111814/1030510627392860263/unknown.png

Comment: So from what I understand, right now the problem is solely with the bat animation getting lost across the import into Unity.   Edit your question to explain how you are transferring.  obj file?  FBX file?   Have you tried to import the transfer file back into a new Blender session, to see if indeed the file is losing information?  (I am not familiar with Unity)